Can I re-cook an undercooked brisket to make it more tender?
I cooked a brisket (with a sauce in a large LeCreuset pot, at 450F covered in foil for 15 minutes then a few hours uncovered at 300F) and impatiently took it out of the oven when its internal temperature reached 200F. It was not very tender.
Can I give it additional cooking time and end up with it being more tender? Should I put it back in the sauce it was cooked in, or cook it dry? Or steam it (no sauce) with a steamer basket? Should I slice it before trying to cook it more?
My impression is that the microwave will not do what I want.
Thanks for any ideas. I

Hi there, when was it cooked? This will determine how long it needs cooking for, because it will need to get back up to a high temperature, then cook

It was cooked yesterday and is in the fridge. Could I possibly get it up to room temperature or higher at low on the microwave? How would I re-cook it (with sauce or dry)?

We've had a few questions about this problem the years...  I don't know if brisket is special in any specific way

related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/63839/67  (and that one then links to other related ones)

Yes, you can recook it for a longer overall slow-cook time. It would be hard to exactly adjust the remaining cooking time for the cooking it's already received, but I think a reasonable approach is to ignore the previous cooking time entirely. It should be cooked in the sauce. Unsliced is probably better... it's tempting to advise you to slice it before cooking longer, since that would make it easier to get nice slices, but I would be worried about those slices absolutely falling into bits during the additional cooking.

slicing it first means that you can make sure there is liquid soaking in and less likely to turn to complete leather.

@Joe A roast like a brisket, with the connective tissue running through, doesn’t need that help. That’s why people are able to slow-cook it as a roast rather than as thin steaks.

If it reached 200F = 93C internally then it is already fully cooked. Depending on personal preferences some people might consider it overcooked already. Giving it the same additional cook time as a raw piece of meat seems way too much.

@quarague With slow cooking like this, it’s not about reaching a particular temperature, or being “fully cooked” in a rare/well-done sense. It’s about leaving it at that temperature while the collagen hydrolyses into gelatin and muscle fibers unbind from each other. That’s a slow process.
